# WireMock set path as dynamic+

Tags: python, java, rest-assured, wiremock, wiremock-standalone

so i have this stub ive created

```
 stubFor(get(urlEqualTo("/skyhost/v1/rms/resourceid/8471jd1da7362f0eb28642s2"))
.willReturn(aResponse().withStatus(200)
.withBodyFile("getstub.json")
.withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")));
```

}

what i wane do is make this dynamic as there might be different resources ID not just the one ive provided in the stub. im confused on how to go about this. i want to be able to provide different resourceid and still be able to get that response back

Answer (score 0):

In the querkus [archive](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus-quickstarts/archive/main.zip) there is an example under the rest-client-quickstart on how to do this:

```
public class WireMockExtensions implements QuarkusTestResourceLifecycleManager {

    private static final String COUNTRIES_JSON_FILE = "/extensions.json";
    private static final String BASE_PATH = "/api";
    private static final int WIREMOCK_PORT = 7777;

    private WireMockServer wireMockServer;

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> start() {
        wireMockServer = new WireMockServer(WIREMOCK_PORT);
        wireMockServer.start();
        stubExtensions();
        return Collections.singletonMap("quarkus.rest-client.\"org.acme.rest.client.ExtensionsService\".url",
                wireMockServer.baseUrl() + BASE_PATH);
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        if (Objects.nonNull(wireMockServer))
            wireMockServer.stop();
    }

    private void stubExtensions() {

        try (InputStream is = WireMockExtensions.class.getResourceAsStream(COUNTRIES_JSON_FILE)) {
            String extensions = new String(is.readAllBytes());

            // Stub for full list of extensions:
            wireMockServer.stubFor(get(urlEqualTo(BASE_PATH))
                    .willReturn(okJson(extensions)));

            // Stub for each country
            try (StringReader sr = new StringReader(extensions);
                    JsonParser parser = Json.createParser(sr)) {
                parser.next();
                for (JsonValue extension : parser.getArray()) {
                    String id = extension.asJsonObject().getString("id");

                    wireMockServer.stubFor(get(urlEqualTo(BASE_PATH + "/extensions?id=" + URLEncoder.encode(id, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)))
                            .willReturn(okJson("[" + extension + "]")));
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            fail("Could not configure Wiremock server. Caused by: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

the `extensions.json`:

```
[
  {
    "id": "io.quarkus:quarkus-rest-client",
    "keywords": [
      "call",
      "microprofile-rest-client",
      "quarkus-rest-client",
      "rest",
      "rest-client",
      "services",
      "web-client"
    ],
    "name": "REST Client",
    "shortName": "REST Client"
  },
  {
    "id": "io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy",
    "keywords": [
      "endpoint",
      "framework",
      "jax",
      "jaxrs",
      "quarkus-resteasy",
      "rest",
      "resteasy",
      "web"
    ],
    "name": "RESTEasy JAX-RS",
    "shortName": "jax-rs"
  }
]
```